# I want to store Ids in data base column

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have  data table with check box when I select multiple rows I get ids. When I select 2 rows the output is like this `2,3` in alert box I want to store the ids in one data base column

This is My code:

```
 $('#create_challan').click(function () {
  //alert('Dispatch Challan submit');

        var allVals = [];
        var saleid = [];
        /*var buttonp = $(this);
            buttonp.addClass('disabled');
            buttonp.text("Working");*/
        $('input[name=selectedBilties]:checked').each(function() {
          allVals.push($(this).val());
          saleid.push($(this).attr('saleid'));
        });

        alert(allVals);
  function allAreEqual(aarray){
    if(!aarray.length)  return false;
    return aarray.reduce(function(a, b){return (a === b)?a:(!b);}) === aarray[0];
    }
```

How can I Store that ids in database.

Comment: call ajax and pass it to server.

Comment: You cannot achieve this in client side Javascript code, you will need to have some server code that will accept a requests from your JavaScript code (using http requests) and that server code should post to the database.

Comment: It is no good idea to store both id's in one column

Comment: can you give me that code @DevsiOdedra

Comment: @ShaikhFarhanSultan you can already google lots of examples of this kind of thing. Just type "ajax php mysql example" into google. Try it, learn about AJAX, and then if you get stuck on something specific, ask us a practical question. There's no point in us re-creating existing tutorials here.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it via ajax send those ids to other page and get it via server side language(php, .net etc), and execute query

```
$.post("pagename", { "id": id,.....}, function (response) { 
});
```